# Access content page elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the .net application with master page and content page. On one of the content pages, I have this code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calendarPicker(strField) {
        window.open('Calendar.aspx?field=' + strField, 'calendarPopup',    'width=230,height=170,resizable=no,top=400,left=600');
    }
```

On the calendar.aspx -

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" Runat="server" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" 
Font-Names="Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial" Font-Size="XX-Small"  >
<TitleStyle BackColor="#b23837" />
</asp:Calendar>

<input type="hidden" id="control" runat="server" name="control"/>
```

and code behind -

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Me.Load
    control.Value = Request.QueryString("field").ToString()
End Sub

Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs)

    ' Clear the link from this day
    e.Cell.Controls.Clear()
    Dim Link As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl()
    Link.TagName = "a"
    Link.InnerText = e.Day.DayNumberText

    Link.Attributes.Add("href",  String.Format("JavaScript:window.opener.document.getElementById('" + control.Value + "').value='{1:d}'; window.close();", Request.QueryString("field"), e.Day.Date))
    If e.Day.IsSelected Then
        Link.Attributes.Add("style", Me.Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.ToString())
    End If
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(Link)
End Sub
```

This works perfect in pages without master page but with master page, the calendar popup appears and nothing happens onclick

Answer (score 0):

Your ID's are not what you think they are. ID's on the server don't necessarily correspond to the ID you see on the client, especially with things like templated controls and master pages.

There's many ways around it. You can refer to things via class, use server side code to embed the client side ID, hardcode the ID to what it will end up being etc. In this case, you might try modifying the site so that the ID's will match. Add this to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I even tried referencing by hard-coding as ctl00$MainContent$TrtmntDate

<a href="javascript:;" id="TrtmntDatecalendar" onclick="calendarPicker('ctl00$MainContent$TrtmntDate');" title="Pick Date from Calendar" runat="server"><img src="images/calendar.gif" border="0" alt="" /></a>